# Changing Ruby versions with rbenv from system and "shell" command does not work

Tags: ruby, rbenv

I can change my rbenv superficially with local and global commands but my Ruby version does not fundamentally change.  My shell command is not recognized but local and global are.  I had RVM previously but uninstalled (as far as I know).  What should I do?

```
$ rbenv versions
  system
* 1.9.3-p0 (set by /Users/geoffreylord/.rbenv/version)
  2.0.0-p247
$ rbenv local
rbenv: no local version configured for this directory
$ rbenv global
1.9.3-p0
$ rbenv shell
rbenv: no such command `shell'
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin12.0]
```

Comment: What do you get if you do a "which ruby", it should return something like "HOME/.rbenv/shims/ruby"

Answer (score 4):

The reason rbenv's `shell command` is called `rbenv-sh-shell` on disk is because `shell` is a special type of command whose output is to be eval'ed in the current interactive shell of the user. This makes it possible for this command to change environment variables in the shell, which is not otherwise possible by simply executing a command.

In order for `rbenv-sh-*` commands to work, rbenv does a little hack by defining the `rbenv()` shell function which executes all rbenv commands normally and eval's the output of `sh-*` commands. So what happens when you run `rbenv shell 2.0` is:

1. `rbenv()` shell function gets called;
2. the function executes `rbenv sh-shell 2.0`;
3. `sh-shell` outputs `export RBENV_VERSION=2.0`;
4. `rbenv()` function eval's that in your current interactive shell.

The `rbenv()` function is installed by the `eval "$(rbenv init -)"` part of the rbenv setup process. (You should have that line in your `.bashrc` or similar init script.) This `init` step is optional (rbenv will work without it) but it does give you tab-completion for rbenv as well as enables `rbenv shell` functionality as described here, as well as any other `sh-*` command that might exists (e.g. those provided by plugins).

Answer (score 0):

Oops! Looks like somebody stuttered.

```
$ ls $HOME/.rbenv/libexec/*shell*
/home/tim/.rbenv/libexec/rbenv-sh-shell
```

Looks like there is no shell command, but rather a sh-shell command

```
$ rbenv sh-shell
rbenv: no shell-specific version configured
```

Yup. Let's see, if we link to it with a rbenv-shell

```
$ cd $HOME/.rbenv/libexec/
$ ln -s rbenv-sh-shell rbenv-shell
```

then we should get a working shell command

```
$ rbenv shell
rbenv: no shell-specific version configured
```

Comment: I still have no idea what to do.


cd $HOME/.rbenv/libexec/
-bash: cd: /Users/geoffreylord/.rbenv/libexec/: No such file or directory

Comment: Also, I still don't know what to do with rbenv.  I've been messing with this for over a week and I'm getting nowhere.

Comment: Hm. [It's working great for me](http://oylenshpeegul.typepad.com/blog/2013/08/acme-envy.html). I guess I don't use the shell command as I've never noticed this. [I've asked about it on github](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/issues/442). We'll see if there's an official response. I doubt my little hack is the answer.